# Solve for a matrix in a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

This is probably a really basic question, but we are stuck and the usual keyword lead to the normal "Solving linear equations with matrices"/Gaussian-elimination pages ...

I have an equation $A X B + C X D  = E$, with $A,B,C,D$ being square matrices and thus, dim(X)=dim(E). Now, with $B=D$ this would be trivial to solve, but in that form, I have no clear idea how to do it easily. It should be possible though, since if I multiply everything, I have as many equations as variables and everything is linear. So I could reshape the matrices to vectors, work with use sparse matrices and so on, but that doesn't sound elegant.

If it makes it somewhat easier, in my case, $B$ is the identity matrix and D only consists of ones. In the end, I want to solve this using MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\def\vec{\mathop{\rm vec}}\vec\colon \def\Mat{\mathop{\rm Mat}}\Mat(n)\to  \mathbb R^{n^2}$ denote vectorisation (columnwise, that is $A_{ij} = \vec(A)_{i+n(j-1)}$) and $\otimes$ the Kronecker product of matrices (`kron` in matlab), then we have 
$$ \vec(AXB) = (B^t \otimes A) \vec(X)$$
Applying this to your equation gives
$$ \vec(E) = \vec(AXB) + \vec(CXD) = (B^t \otimes A + C^t\otimes D)\vec(X) $$
Now solve for $\vec(X)$ an reshape.

Comment: That is at least an elegant solution for the vectorization and does the job. Thanks.
Still a bit surprised (or perhaps a bit glad, since then I am not completely stupid :)) that there isn't an easy solution without reshaping. I'll flag this as the solution if nothing into that direction comes up.

Comment: @mcandril I do not know if there is a more 'direct' solution without vectorisation, but I doubt. For general $A$ it seems a problem to solve $AX + XA = E$ without vectorization.

Comment: Hm, ok, thanks. The problem I am facing now is 70kx70k matrix from the Kronecker product :)